# How are Order States/Statuses translated?

Tags: localisation, order-status

Suppose I have a website with English and German store views. I only see a single global mapping of states to statuses at /admin/sales_order_status, so it's not clear how I would have an order state show up differently in different languages. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the configuration for the statuses you can provide label translations on a per-store basis (from the backend):

In System > Order Statuses > [Click on Status]:

[image]